# Template::Tookit, show template name in the html source automatically

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

when using perl's Template::Tookit, is there a way to make it show the template name/path in the html (e.g. commented with <!-- .. -->), to make it easier to find relative template.

Many thanks.

UPDATE:
[% template.name %] isn't really helping as I don't know which template to put it to :)
I'm dealing with a 3rd party software with a few hundred templates, so I was hoping there is some way of enabling it on a Template engine level globally.

Comment: `[% template.name %]`?

Comment: [% template.name %] isn't really helping as I don't know which template to put it to :)
I'm dealing with a 3rd party software with a few hundred templates, so I was hoping there is some way of enabling it on a Template engine level globally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `[% template.name %]` and `[% component.name %]`

The **component** variable **is like template but always contains a reference to the current, innermost template component being processed**.

Example:

```
$template->process('foo')
    || die $template->error(), "\n";
```

foo template:

```
[% template.name %]         # foo
[% component.name %]        # foo
[% PROCESS footer %]
```

footer template:

```
[% template.name %]         # foo
[% component.name %]        # footer
```

**Edit**: Try `Template->new(PRE_PROCESS => 'template_name', ...)` then put the `[% template.name %]` inside a file called template_name.

Comment: [% template.name %] isn't really helping as I don't know which template to put it to :)
I'm dealing with a 3rd party software with a few hundred templates, so I was hoping there is some way of enabling it on a Template engine level globally.

Answer (score 1):

As documented [`Variables: template`](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Variables.html#section_template)

```
[% template.name %]
```

Comment: [% template.name %] isn't really helping as I don't know which template to put it to :)
I'm dealing with a 3rd party software with a few hundred templates, so I was hoping there is some way of enabling it on a Template engine level globally.